# Android UI to Enter List Edit Mode

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a short list of items in my activity. I want to add a button somewhere in the UI to switch to edit mode for the list of items. I'm new to Android programming and even to using Android devices. I'm accustomed to iOS. In an iOS table, there is usually an "Edit" button in the top right of the navigation bar. What is the standard way in Android to switch to edit mode in a list? (Is there a standard way?)

When in edit mode, I plan to show edit (e.g. pencil) and delete (e.g. 'X') buttons on the right side of each list item's view.

I don't think it is related but just in case...I'm not using `RecyclerView` or anything fancy. Just `LinearLayout`. The list is so short I don't think there is a performance reason to use a recycler. Is there any other reason to use a `RecyclerView`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to action mode. Example:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ActionMode actionMode;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (actionMode == null)
            actionMode = startActionMode(callback);
        else
            actionMode.finish();
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "item " + item.getTitle());
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
            actionMode = null;
        }

    };

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you, KMI. I'll experiment with `ActionMode`. While I needed to know about `ActionMode` too, what is the usual UI element in Android that the user presses to start an `ActionMode`? For example, in an iOS table it is an "Edit" button in the top right of the navigation bar.

Comment: You can add menu in your activity and when user clicks in edit menu start action mode. In action mode you update your recyclerview and tell him show delete or select actions.